# Adjust particle file (.plist) in real time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, particle-system

I have a cocos2 project I'm working on and I'm wondering if there is a way to adjust a variable in my particle system .plist file in real time. i.e. adjust the x gravity to correlate with the speed of the player etc. I'm using particle designer to make the files initially.

Any suggestions or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you initialize the particle from the file, just modify it's properties like you would to any other particle.

Open the particles header file (CCParticle.h, probably) to see what properties it has and what you can modify.